# Create Angular directive that keeps original element's attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've seen other SO questions that kind of ask this, but they usually have some unique complication thrown in, and the answer seems surprisingly complicated in proportion to the simplicity of the desired result. I'd like to ask the simplest possible version of this question.

Let's say I have a directive that looks like this:

```
<my-input type="text" placeholder="foo">
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="foo" class="bar">
```

All I want to do is output a new element and add some new attributes, but keep the original element's attributes. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Use an attribute for the directive rather than an element: `<input type="text" placeholder="foo" my-directive>`. And make myDirective add the desired new attributes to its element.

Comment: I do believe your comment is the right answer. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Right. I made it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an attribute for the directive rather than an element:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="foo" my-directive>
```

And make `myDirective` add the desired new attributes to its element.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is not straight forward way to copy all attributes from one element to another, so you would need to loop through then or know what ones you want to support.

The following is the start of a directive that will replace the element the has the directive with a different element (input, in this case)

```
.directive('myInput', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            var inputElem = angular.element('input');

            // Copy attributes from element to inputElem;
            angular.forEach(element[0].attributes, function(attr) {
                inputElem[0].setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value);
            })

            // Add new attributes

            return inputElem;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You directive template function will give access to your all attributes defined on element. You can easily add those attribute inside html element.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myInput', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: function(element, attrs){
       var template = '<input type="'+ attrs.text +'"/>'
       //add other attributes from here
       return template;
    }
  }
});
```